# The Proper Class Design For Designing a Language Type System

Tags: language-design, type-systems

I am designing a language for my own purposes. It will have two entities basically, functions and types. e.g.

```
Object1 = CreateObject1("param1", "param2", 23 ) //Line 1
Object3 = Object1 + Object2 //Line 2
Evaluate(Object3) //Line 3
```

Line 2 evaluates if object of type Object1 be "+" to Object2 and if yes then a resultant object will be created and will be assigned to Object3. The variable definitions are like var keyword in Java Script.

The design in my mind is like creating a base "Value" class (having primitive operations like add, subtract, multiply, divide etc) having concrete children each corresponding to different types which I plan to ingest in the language.

```
class Value{
 Value add(Value value)
 ..
}

class Integer extends Value{
 Value add(Value value){
    //if value is compatible to add with Integer type then return the appropriate     
    //resultant object else throw exception.
 }
}
```

I can create children classes like that easily but if a function changes the attributes of a object (like a member value be changed of a class) then I need to downcast to it to that type and update the appropriate property.

```
class ABC extends Value{
 Value add(Value value){
 //
 }

 private int X;
 private int Y;
 private int Z;
 private string XYZ;

 public setX(int x){
   this.X = x;
 }
 .
 .
}

ObjectABC = GetABC();
SetX(ObjectABC, 1)
```

In the implemenatiob of the function SetX(). I will be doing something like this:

```
ABC abc = (ABC)ObjectABC; //ObjectABC will be a Value type here.
abc.setX( 1 );
```

I want to get rid of this down casting thing. Can it be done? Please advise.

Comment: There are usually ways to eliminate casting, but I think you'll need to provide more information on what exactly you're doing.   For example, who defined the ABC object?  Is that defined in your language or defined in Java?  At the least, try showing a full example program in your language.

Comment: ABC is the implementation details of ObjectABC object which is in my language. The language structure is like that. 

/*@list will have Employee objects*/
@employeeList = GetEmployess("AdminBlock")  
/*@avgSalary will have double value */
@avgSalary = GetAvgSalary(@list)    
@SumCalculation = ( @avgSalary * 33 ) / 100

Answer (score 0):

You could use double dispatch like so:

```
abstract class Value {
   Value add(Value v) { throw new InvalidArgumentException("add", getClass(), v); }
   Value addInteger(Integer i);

   Value divide(Value) { throw new InvalidArgumentException("divide", getClass(), v); }
   Value divideIntegerReversed(Integer i);

}

class Integer extends Value {
   @Override
   Value add(Value v) {
     return v.addInteger(this);
   }

   @Override      
   Value addInteger(Integer other) {
      // note the argument reversal but not worries because addition is commutative
      return whtvr;
   }

   @Override
   Value divide(Value v) {
     return v.divideIntegerReversed(this);
   }

   @Override
   Value divideIntegerReversed(Integer nom) {
     // note that we now want `nom / this` and not `this / nom`
     return wthvr;
   }
}
```